eBay API createFulfillmentPolicy returning error 2003
I am trying to create a fulfillment policy on my sandbox environment, but i am getting error 2003. Anyone has any idea how to fix it?
p.s. i am using API Explorer to send the request, and it worked for PaymentPolicy and ReturnPolicy.
Body:
{
  "categoryTypes": [  
   {
     "name": "ALL_EXCLUDING_MOTORS_VEHICLES"
   }
  ],
  "marketplaceId": "EBAY_US",
  "name": "Worldwide Shipping",
  "handlingTime": {
    "unit" : "DAY",
    "value" : "7"
  }
}

Response:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 2003,
      "domain": "ACCESS",
      "category": "APPLICATION",
      "message": "Internal error",
      "longMessage": "There was a problem with an eBay internal system or process. Contact eBay developer support for assistance"
    }
  ]
}

I also tried sending another object in the body, based on the API docs https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/account/resources/fulfillment_policy/methods/createFulfillmentPolicy, but still the same isssue.

I'm getting this same error :(
